# Bad practice to use Context as static variable?

Tags: android, static, resources, android-context

I have a question regarding the use of Context as a static variable.

My code goes something like this

```
public class MyClass{
   private static Context con = AnotherClass.getContext();
   private static String fileName = con.getResources().getString(R.string.file_name);

   //rest of the code
}
```

Is it bad practice to implement it this way? I need the filename to be read when the class is created because I have some other static methods inside it that might be called at any time.

The app works fine and as intended. I was just wondering if there are any downside of this implementation.

Comment: Do not keep long-lived references to a context-activity (a reference to an activity should have the same life cycle as the activity itself). http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: You can use an Application class and expose a static method to get the ApplicationContext.

Comment: @Atrix1987 Hi, that's exactly what i'm doing. the getContext() method returns the ApplicationContext from another class that extends the Application.

Comment: ok, so you are sub classing Application Context. It should be fine if you are getting the ApplicationContext from the Application class. Alternative, if you dnt want to subclass Application http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()